# How to get company description when you only know the name of the company?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, google-chrome

I am working on one project where I need to pre-fill the company Information. I only have the Company Name.
Does anyone have any idea how can I do that?
We are using Nodejs and React in our project.

Comment: hey are you storing anywhere the description or any api to give you the required desc?

Comment: That's exactly my question. It would not be an optimal way to store the data so I need an API through which I can get the data

Comment: so, what you can do is: on filling the reuired data , make an api call with that data and fetch the value and show it in box